# What can I use to fill in space around new registers that are smaller than the old ones?

Tags: baseboard, gap, register

We've been replacing our baseboard registers with newer ones since the old ones are discolored and beat up. I didn't know that they weren't a standard size, so I bought registers that are the same width as the old ones. Unfortunately, the ones we bought are shorter and not as deep as the old ones, so we have some space on top and in front (see pictures). Is there anything we can use to fill the gaps that would look okay? I don't think we can return these, so we'd have to buy new registers if not.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "I don't think we can return these" it may be worth finding out for sure. Many retailers do actually value keeping their customers happy, and even if official company policy may not allow for returning an opened item, many individual managers realize that making the human standing in front of them happy, helps keep the customer coming back.

Comment: I got them from Home Depot -- I guess there's no harm in trying to bring them back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you do will still look like you bought registers that were the wrong size and used them anyway. You could fill in the areas with caulk or grout and then try to match the color with the surronding area and paint the gaps.

I would try to return them. Most home stores are pretty understandable with home improvement returns. If not, just keep shopping around. This is one of those things that will continue to bug you if you don't do it right.

Comment: Or, slap 'em in with the expectation of replacing them in the future when they get to be annoying enough.